# Rest call using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, get

I am trying to obtain the returned information from the following URL using jQuery:

```
Var URL = http://getdeeplink.linksynergy.com/createcustomlink.shtml?token=2e9830b7ed11c5dee96dd4b4a9e83da216c9d583ae1e617bcafdd6eb004e3c86&mid=13508&murl=http://itunes.apple.com/us/music-video/if-you-think-this-song-is/id413824018?uo=4
```

I have tried the two approaches outlined below, but in both cases the program just runs past the code blocks like nothing happened. Can any one tell what I'm doing wrong?

```
  $.ajax({ 
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "jsonp",
             url: URL,
             success: function(data){       
                alert(data);
             }
         });
```

Second Approach:

```
     $.get(URL, function(data) {
       alert('Load was performed.');
       alert(data);
      });
```

Comment: When going to that link in the browser all it outputs is the url I entered. You sure the url your using is correct? I'm assuming you are trying get get some actual data.

Comment: You don't get the alert?

Comment: put "quotes" around the url string

Comment: ^ and `var` is all lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

First off, if the domain of the server you are requesting the URL is not the same as the domain of your page, then you may be running into [same-origin-limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Second, If it's not the same origin and you're trying to use JSONP (which is looks like you might be), then your server will need to specifically support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and package the result in JSONP format which means formatting the result as an executable script and also means respecting the `callback=xxxx` query argument on the URL.

Third, this piece of javascript you put in your question looks like it's missing quotes around the URL to make it legal javascript and `var` is all lowercase:

```
var URL = "http://getdeeplink.linksynergy.com/createcustomlink.shtml?token=2e9830b7ed11c5dee96dd4b4a9e83da216c9d583ae1e617bcafdd6eb004e3c86&mid=13508&murl=http://itunes.apple.com/us/music-video/if-you-think-this-song-is/id413824018?uo=4";
```

For further debugging, I would suggest that you attach an error handler for the ajax call and see if that provides any further information.  If something is being blocked due to same-origin issues or you just have other script errors that are stopping execution of your script, then your browser error console or debug console may also offer you a helpful message.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform an ajax call like that because of same origin limitation.
What you need to do is setup a server side page which your java script will perform an ajax call on say 'getdeeplink.php' (I'm assuming you are doing it in PHP)

Your javascript

```
$.get('getdeeplink.php',data,function(){.....});
```

Its in getdeeplink.php where you perform the REST call and echo back the response to the ajax handler

In `getdeeplink.php`

```
$rest_response = file_get_contents('http://getdeeplink.linksynergy.com/createcustomlink.shtml?token=2e9830b7ed11c5dee96dd4b4a9e83da216c9d583ae1e617bcafdd6eb004e3c86&mid=13508&murl=http://itunes.apple.com/us/music-video/if-you-think-this-song-is/id413824018?uo=4');
echo json_encode($rest_response); //send the result to the ajax handler
```