# Making API Rest call using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, open-source

I'm trying to make a REST call from jquery to a rest service.
I am going to consume data from [OpenMRS API](https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/API).
I was following the instructors of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442588/rest-call-using-jquery) post.

Now, I made the call , but still stacking with parsing the object to Json and showing it on the HTML Page. I got problems in doing that. I am sharing code on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/11/) JSFiddle.

What are the different steps to parse JSon response ?

To explore the object , I am using Chrome Console. I wrote this line as an example of can I consume data (Observation in this case):

```
 `$('#result').html('<p>' + data[0].concept +  '<p>');`
```

'

Answer (score 0):

In your example data is already an object.
Si you just navigate through it like any other object;

ex:

```
$('#result').html('<p>' + data.results[0].concept.display +  '<p>');
```

On the js put :

```
success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
```

So you can use the chrome console to see how the object is made.
Below a partial exemple of the console.log output:

```
Object {results: Array[15]}
results: Array[15]
0: Object
accessionNumber: null
comment: null
concept: Object
display: "Patient Record Image"
links: Array[1]
uuid: "raxa00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000023"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: How can I show this object within the HTML page ! as it's not working out ?

Comment: What do you want to display, a var_dump like of the object or some information inside it?

Comment: I wanna display object fields , for example :  "data.results[0].concept.display" ?

Comment: Well if you want to display the image, it's encoded in base64, so you can do that : var img = data.results[0].value;
            
            $('#result').html("<img id='img1'>");
            $('#img1').attr('src', img);

Comment: Thanks , what about showing all the images - I wrote a function (check the UPDATE Part)

Comment: Well you should just loop on the result array with my code example, don't forget to iterate on the id so it goes img1 img2 etc....

Comment: I made it this way , but it doesn't work out : 
                 $.each(data, function(i,item){
        var img = data.results[i].value; 
        $("<img/>").attr("src", img).appendTo("#result");
 
    });